# Compare two columns and display "Yes" or "no"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to compare column E and F but the "Vrai" should be "Oui" I can't figure how to change the formula?

I'am using `=ET(E2=F2)`

I was expecting doing something like : `=SI(E2=F2; "Oui", "Non"` but it ain't working...

Help is very welcome

[image]

Comment: Excel OR google sheets?

Comment: Please use proper #Tags -> Excel is not GS neither GS is Excel, though both looks alike but there are lot of difference in their functionality, please confirm,!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In google sheets

```
=SI(E2=F2; "Oui"; "Non")
```

should work...

Comment: okay... it was `;` instead of `,`